# Why custom Exception was not catch by expectException method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-testing

Making tests on laravel 9 site I try to catch custom Exception and looking at this
[Undefind withoutExceptionHandling()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61223387/undefind-withoutexceptionhandling)
example I do in my tests

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

//use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Article;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ArticlesCrudTest extends TestCase
{
    use InteractsWithExceptionHandling;

    public function testNegativeArticleGotFailureWithInactiveUserToBeAdded()
    {
        $loggedUser = clone(self::$loggedUser);


        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();


        $loggedUser->status = 'I' ; // Inactive
        $newArticleObject = \App\Models\Article::factory(Article::class)->make();

        $response = $this->actingAs($loggedUser, 'api')->post(route('articles.store'),
            $newArticleObject->toArray());

        $this->expectException(\App\Exceptions\UserAccountManagerAccessException::class);

        $response->assertStatus(400);
    }
```

But I got error message :

here was 1 error:

```
1) Tests\Feature\ArticlesCrudTest::testNegativeArticleGotFailureWithInactiveUserToBeAdded
App\Exceptions\UserAccountManagerAccessException: Your account must be active in "store" !

/ProjectPath/app/Library/Services/LocalUserAccountManager.php:59
/ProjectPath/app/Repositories/ArticleCrudRepository.php:191
/ProjectPath/app/Http/Controllers/ArticleController.php:86
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:43
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:260
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:205
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:725
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:141
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:50
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:180
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php:126
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php:102
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php:54
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:180
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php:44
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:180
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:116
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:726
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:703
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:667
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:656
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:190
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:141
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:21
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php:31
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:180
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:21
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php:40
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:180
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:180
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php:86
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:180
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php:62
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:180
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php:39
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:180
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:116
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:165
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:134
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:545
/ProjectPath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:340
/ProjectPath/tests/Feature/ArticlesCrudTest.php:108

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Yes, valid exception UserAccountManagerAccessException was raised, but why methods expectException and $response->assertStatus did not work and my
test did not passed with sucess?

**TOPIC DETAILS:**
In routes/api.php :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api') ->group(function () {

    Route::apiResource('articles', ArticleController::class);
```

in app/Http/Controllers/ArticleController.php Repository method is called:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $this->articleCrudRepository->store(data: $request->only('title', 'text', 'text_shortly',
        'creator_id', 'published'), makeValidation: true);
}
```

and in  app/Repositories/ArticleCrudRepository.php Repository :

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories;

...
class ArticleCrudRepository 
{

    public function store(array $data, bool $makeValidation = false): JsonResponse|MessageBag
    {
        ...    
         $this->userAccountManager->checkPermissions( [ ], "store");
        // UserAccountManagerAccessException is raised in method above, BEFORE try block with transaction...
        
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $article = Article::create([
                'title'        => $data['title'],
                'text'         => $data['text'],
                'text_shortly' => $data['text_shortly'],
                'creator_id'   => $data['creator_id'],
                'published'    => $data['published'],
            ]);
            DB::Commit();

            $article->load('creator');

            return response()->json(['article' => (new ArticleResource($article))],  201); 
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
            \Log::info($errorMessage);
            DB::rollback();

            return sendErrorResponse($e->getMessage(), 500);
        }
    }




"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",
"laravel/passport": "^11.3",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: fyi, `public function test)` is invalid code

Comment: You're showing the `test()` method, but the error refers to the `testNegativeArticleGotFailureWithInactiveUserToBeAdded()` method

Comment: Sorry, Error in topic fixed.

Comment: You really should show `route('articles.store')`, the function of course

Comment: I added description articles.store and related issues in TOPIC DETAILS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to set such order:

```
$this->expectException(\App\Exceptions\UserAccountManagerAccessException::class);
```

And after that :

```
    $response = $this->actingAs($loggedUser, 'api')->post(route('articles.store')
```

That works!